# Getting data from sql database and then use it for select query via php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this allocation table:

```
PROJECT_ID | NAME_ID
1                1
1                2
2                1
2                2
```

My php Code looks as following:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx") 
    or die ("Connection failed");
mysql_select_db("xxx") 
    or die ("Connection failed");
$res = mysql_query("SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM Projects_Names WHERE NAME_ID=1 AND 2");
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);
echo "$num Projects found<br />";

while($dsatz = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
echo $dsatz["PROJECT_ID"] . "<br />";
}

?>
```

This will then give me the following output:

```
2 Projects found
1
2
```

So far so good. But what I basically want is to find out the names of the projects where employee 1 and employee 2 are both involved in. I have two more tables. A Projects table with the project Name, ID etc... and a Employee table with Name, ID etc...

I basically now want to say:

"look in the Projects table for the IDs that were just given as output (1,2) and give me the names of these projects"

I hope someone will give me some input on how to solve this, I just started sql + php yesterday, so theres much to learn :)

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM Projects_Names WHERE NAME_ID in (1,2)";`

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a combination of `GROUP BY` with `COUNT` and `HAVING` to get what you want

```
SELECT project_id, COUNT(DISTINCT name_id) AS `name_count`
FROM projects_names
WHERE name_id IN (?,?,...)
GROUP BY project_id
HAVING `name_count` = n
```

Here you would list all name_id values you were interested in and `n` would equal the number of name_id values search for.  So if you are looking for name_id 1 and 2, you would use n = 2.  This means find all projects where those to id are working, but there could be additional name_id's involved as well (those wouldn't be included in the count as they were filtered out).

Comment: Thanks Mike, this works great. But the output of the project IDs isnt my problem. The Output in the example is 1 and 2 (these are the Project_IDs where 1 and 2 are working together, so "1" and "2" as numbers are both used as Name_ID and Project_ID)

So Output is 1 and 2. Now I wanna look for 1 and 2 in my Projects Table and extract Project_Name from Projects via the Project_ID.

I need to somehow store the output and use it again to query against the Project table I assume...not sure though.

Comment: @user2511119 You would just join the project table to this query. Something like `SELECT p.project_name AS project, COUNT(DISTINCT pn.name_id) AS `name_count` FROM project_names AS pn INNER JOIN projects AS p ON pn.project_id = p.project_id WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong syntax. You should either write it separately like this:

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM Projects_Names WHERE NAME_ID=1 AND NAME_ID = 2");
```

or use `in`

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM Projects_Names WHERE NAME_ID in (1,2)");
```

Comment: If I use OR wouldnt this tell the engine to give me all projects where either 1 or 2 are involved? I want to find out in which projects they have been working togeher.

Comment: Thanks for the input. If I use

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM Projects_Names WHERE NAME_ID in (1,2)");

The output is: 4 Projects found. 1 1 2 2

If I use it with mysqli_query($con it will give me "Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters [...] error.

It still doesnt give me the names for project 1 and 2 corresponding in table Projects...I need to connect the output to the names in a diffrent table.

1 = Project Winter
2 = Project Sun

Thats what I want to see as output :)

Comment: The first parameter has to be $connection. Look it up.